# Check if default billing address in checkout - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, knockoutjs, billing-address

Inside the checkout `/app/design/theme/theme/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` file I would like to check if the customer does have a default billing address.

Is there a knockout possibility to check this? Something like:

```
<!-- ko if: (customerHasAddresses && isAddressFormListVisible)-->
    Got default address
<!-- /ko -->
```

But the code above does not seem to work in this template.

Comment: In shipping.js in ```web/js/view/shipping``` you can get customer object which contains 'getBillingAddressList'. Maybe this will give you information about default billing address. 
For tests you can modify shipping.html simply add ```<div data-bind="text: console.log(getPopUp())"></div>```. And in shipping.js in method getPopUp at the begining put ```return customer```

Comment: Thanks @SebastianT! Sadly we also can not get the required information from there.

Comment: If you use ```getPopUp().getBillingAddressList()``` you will get list of billign addresses. And for each address you have method ```isDefaultBilling``` which return true if address is default or null. 
```getPopUp().getBillingAddressList()[1].isDefaultBilling()```

Comment: @SebastianT Thanks! So in that case it will be? `<!-- ko if: getPopUp().getBillingAddressList()[1].isDefaultBilling()-->`

Comment: something like this. But you do not know if first, second or third address is default. So you have to do for/foreach loop through ```getPopUp().getBillingAddressList()``` and check if current address is default. unfortunately i'm not an expert in magento / koJS, so you have to search some information how to do foreach loop and get current element. Hope you will do this. If you have any questions, let me know, i will try to help you.

Comment: @SebastianT Is there an easier way to check if there is any billing address at all?

Comment: Sure ```getPopUp().getBillingAddressList()``` this will return array if there is a billing address.

Comment: @SebastianT Thanks! But it seems that it always display a yes trough `<!-- ko if: getPopUp().getBillingAddressList()-->` even if the customer does not have any billing addresses.

Comment: ```getPopUp().getBillingAddressList().length``` return ```0``` if there is no billing address.

Comment: @SebastianT Also does not seem to work. Seems that it returns true, because there is a address, but this is not selected as billing address.

Comment: <!-- ko if: getPopUp().getBillingAddressList().length > 0 --> something like this should work. you need also add closing tag <!-- /ko -->

Comment: @SebastianT That's what I exactly tried, but in that case it returns true. Even if there is non billing address. There is only 1 shipping address, but it still returns true.

Comment: and if you use ```<div data-bind="text: console.log(getPopUp().getBillingAddressList().length)"></div>``` what it returns?

Comment: That does not return anything, just a white page.

Comment: but in web browser console.

Comment: @SebastianT That does not display any relevant error

Comment: you should not get any error.  Right click inspect element then console tab, and you should get information about billing address list length. For test you can write <div data-bind="text: console.log('test message')"></div> and check if this template and ko code works. In console you should get "test message"

Comment: @SebastianT Thanks, sadly it seems that we still need to check if there is a default billing address, instead of a address. Otherwise it will return `true`, even if there is no default billing address. Any idea how to implement this in this .html template?

Comment: ```.getBillingAddressList().length``` return number of billing addresses customer saved. it will be 0 for guest and if you create account and didnt fill address.

Comment: @SebastianT Thanks, but that's the main issue in our case, because we have customers that do have address, but not default Billing address. So therefore we need to check if there is a default billing address.